# How do I extrude edges easily like in Max?

Tags: transforms, edges, extrude

In 3ds Max, there is a function which allows you to [shift+drag](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blaccpwjpz8&t=60) an edge on an editable poly. This would create a new quad, with one edge being the edge you started with, and the opposite edge being the one your cursor holds. This function is pretty essential for me, and I have yet to find a similar function in Blender. 
The function can be used in combination with scale, rotate, or move, and can be used with any number of polys selected.

Comment: Ctrl-LMB is a shortcut for extrude. An addon would need to be made to more closely replicate the max tool.

Comment: Do you happen to know of any addons like that?